# Do exact faithful functors between triangulated categories detect semi-simplicity?

Tags: triangulated-categories

Recall that in a triangulated category, all monomorphisms split (have a retraction). Let $F:C\to D$ be an exact functor between triangulated categories. It is an easy exercise to see that if $F$ is faithful then it detects monomorphisms: If $F(f)$ is a monomorphism then so is $f$. Same with epimorphisms of course, and with isomorphisms. But what about semi-simplicity in the following sense?

> **Definition**: Let us say that a morphism $f$ is *semi-simple* if there exists $g$ in the opposite direction such that $f=fgf$. (BTW, what is the right name for this?) Assuming $C$ idempotent-complete, $f$ is semi-simple $\iff$ $f$ is a composition of a split epimorphism, an isomorphism and a split monomorphism $\iff$ the exact triangle over $f$ is a sum of trivial triangles.

After trying for a while, I suspect that $F$ faithful is not enough to detect semi-simplicity, so:

> **Problem**: Find an exact faithful functor $F:C\to D$ between idempotent-complete triangulated categories and a morphism $f$ in $C$ which is not semi-simple but such that $F(f)$ is semi-simple in $D$.

Of course, it might also be true that faithfulness detects semi-simplicity. A proof of that would certainly count as an answer to the above problem!

What would make me really happy would be to have $F=(\ F:C\to C\ ,\ \mu:F^2\to F\ ,\ \eta:Id\to F\ )$ an exact faithful *monad* (a.k.a. triple) on the category $C=D$. In that case, $F$ faithful forces the unit $\eta$ to be objectwise a split monomorphism. If $\eta$ has moreover a natural retraction then $F$ detects semi-simplicity (easy) but this naturality of the retraction definitely fails for general monads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non semi-simple algebra and $C$ be the derived category of finite dimensional
$A-$modules. Let $D$ be the derived category of finite dimensional vector spaces and let
$F$ be the forgetful functor which maps $A-$module to its underlying vector space. 
Then $F(f)$ is semi-simple for any $f$ (since any morphism in $D$ is semisimple).

UPDATE: as explained below this is not an answer since $F$ is not faithful. Here is an actual example: take for $C$ derived category of representations of an ADE quiver; let $D$ be as above and
let $F=RHom(T,?)$ where $T$ is a direct sum of all indecomposable representations of the quiver
(there are just finitely many of them). Then $F(f)$ is semi-simple for any $f$ as before; to check
that $F$ is faithful use the fact that any object of $C$ is isomorphic to direct sum of shifted
indecomposable representations of the quiver (since the category of representations of the quiver
has homological dimension 1).

Comment: But why is $F$ faithful?

Comment: Um... *forgetful* functor?

Comment: At the derived level it is going to kill the morphisms representing non-trivial extensions though...

Comment: @Victor: Take A=kG for a (finite) group G and k a field. In D(kG), the homs from k to suspensions of k are the cohomology groups of G with coefficients in k. When you go to D(k) under the (dangerously named) forgetful functor, all the (positive) cohomology groups go to zero

Comment: sorry, my functor is not faithful. I think quick and dirty fix would
be to consider direct sum of all representable functors (sum over all isomorphism classes of indecomposable objects in $C$); of course
in this case $D$ will consist of all complexes (not just finite dimensional ones).. Is this any better?

Comment: @Victor: Since I'm not familiar with ADE quivers, this answer is not clear to me, sorry (my fault). Is it so important to have the representations of an ADE quiver or can you translate the example in terms a suitable abelian category with conditions (generator?, homological dimension) and then say that the representations of the ADE quiver form such an example. That should be easier for me to digest. Many thanks!

Comment: @Paul: You are welcome! I need the following properties: homological dimension 1 (this would be true for any quiver); finitely many indecomposables (this is specific to ADE). Both of these is really needed only in order to avoid infinite dimensional vector spaces in the category $D$. 

Comment: @Victor: Thanks, I think I'm convinced. Since you're inspired: Can you make it monadic (see the end of my question)? Does your $F$ admit a right adjoint?

Comment: I am probably missing something but I am not convinced, at least not that having homological dimension 1 and a finite (up to suspension) set of generators is sufficient to produce a counterexample in general. For instance, working over an alg. closed field say, $\mathrm{Coh}\;\mathbb{P}^1$ has homological dimension 1 and $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ generate $D^b(\mathbb{P}^1)$. The functor $RHom(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(1),-)$ is certainly faithful - it is an equivalence with the representations of the Kronecker quiver. The point is that the image of every map is not semisimple.

Comment: @Greg: I suppose, strictly speaking, the example is $RHom(T,?)$  composed with the forgetful functor to $D$ . In $D=D(k)$, every map is semi-simple. Does this make sense?